# Dont copy method description from parent/interface, insert @inheritdoc instead

Tags: phpstorm

When overriding or implementing methods from a parent class or interface in PhpStorm there is a feature (among others) to create method stubs for the missing methods automatically via the Quick Fix menu (`Alt+Enter`). This feature also creates a method description if one is found.

How can I make this feature by default create an `@inheritdoc` method description (if one exists), instead of copying the entiry method description of the parent?

**Update**: See the end of the accepted answer (relating to the Quick Fix menu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well .. PhpStorm **2016.3.2** (latest stable version) -- such option is just there for both `Code | Implement Methods...` and `Code | Override Methods...`

[image]

Obviously, the method that gets overridden/implemented **must have PHPDoc comment in base class** for this to work properly.

---

**For "quick fix" actions** (accessible via <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> or light bulb icon) that allow to quickly implement ALL missing interface methods and/or abstract methods declared in parent class this is indeed not possible ATM.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-27869 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Comment: I am aware,  but I want the same option for the cases when I am not opening that specific tool window,  but use a keyboard shortcut. Will update my question to reflect that.

Comment: @bblue What shortcuts exactly? Those 2 actions are accessible via shortcuts as well (`Ctrl+O` and `Ctrl+I` using Default keymap) and the most obvious to use based on your description. You better describe your exact step where your "other" shortcuts are used. It's possible that you are talking about Quick Fix menu (`Alt+Enter` .. or via light bulb icon). Those ones indeed do not use `@inheritDoc` -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-27869 ... but such quick fix is available for implementing interface/abstract methods .. and not for overriding random method from base class.

Comment: I am speaking of the `Alt+Enter` version. The issue you referenced is spot on.